# Deserializing entity without aware of its type

Tags: c#, json, generics

I came up with this problem in my project, i have a json string from table, it is a serialized entity.
**Json**

```
{
"Entity":{
"__type":"Book:#Definition",
"BookId":3,
"BookName":"Meloon Dreams",
"Type":2,
"Price":35
}
}
```

**Book Class**

```
namespace Definition
{
   [DataContract]
   public class Book : IEntity
   {
       [DataMember]
       public int BookId { get; set; }

       [DataMember]
       public string BookName { get; set; }

       [DataMember]
       public BookType Type { get; set; }

       [DataMember]
       public decimal Price { get; set; }
   }
}
```

**Workflow Class**

```
public class Workflow
{
    public int WorkflowId { get; set; }

    public IEntity Entity { get; set; }
}
```

So, in a controller class i get the json string from table and i want to deserialize it to its own type. But, only the *__type* inside the json string helps me with its type. What i mean is

```
workflow.Entity = Serializer.JsonDeserialize<IEntity>(jsonString);
```

i need to put **Book** instead of *IEntity*

Is that possible without changing the class structures, or is it possible to get the type from json and convert it to type and put it instead IEntity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to instantiate generic classes dynamically specifying generic type. It is possible to do it with reflection:

```
// Load type name from json - you'll need to implement LoadTypeFromJson() method to load type name string from json
string typeName = LoadTypeFromJson();

// Get .Net Type by type name
Type entityType = Type.GetTypeByName(typeName);

// Get Serializer type
Type serializerType = typeof(Serializer);

// Get MethodInfo for Deserialize method of Serializer class
MethodInfo deserializeMethodInfo = serializerType.GetMethod("Deserialize");

// Construct Serializer.Deserialize<IEntity> method for specific IEntity
MethodInfo constructedDeserializeMethod = deserializeMethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(entityType);

// Call constructed method
constructedDeserializeMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { jsonString });
```

The key part here is [MethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.makegenericmethod.aspx)

Comment: The question helped a bit but, in my project i am not using a generic class, it is a generic method. What i mean is that my workflow entity property needs an explicit type not a generic type. So i need to convert json entity to its own type and pass it to deserializer. However i will keep inspecting on this reflection. Thanks.

Comment: I have updated the answer with a code sample, and also changed a link to a more appropriate one (about MakeGenericMethod method) - hopefully it helps

Comment: I had to change my class structure for my purpose. Because the type what my entity to be converted in json was kept in the json :) It is a paradox, i need to parse the json with string methods to get the type, so i decided to change my class structure. But i marked this post as answer because i achieved my purpose with that way as well and covers the topic. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @ibubi you can pre-parse to a more general object with just the type property. Once you read the type, parse again with a more concrete type.